# C Pyramid Character-Pattern

Tags: c

So , after hours of work i finally get to make the pattern. However, even after using _getchar() function i cannot close the output window. Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
char ch, j = ' ';
char ch1 = 'A';
char row;
char col1;
char spaces;
char col2;
printf("Enter a character\n");
while (scanf_s("%c", &ch, 1) == 1)
{
    for (row = 'A'; row <= ch; row++)
    {
        // This stmt was only tracker printf("%c", row);
        for (spaces = ch; spaces >= row; spaces--)
        {
            printf("%c", j);
        }
        for (col1 = ch1; col1 <= row; col1++)
        {
            printf("%c", col1);
        }

        for (col2 = col1 - 2; col2 >= ch1; --col2)
        {
            printf("%c", col2);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    break;
}
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

I feel like mission accomplished, it was a trickier problem. Still i m not happy to use break statement. Whenever the patterns is formed on the screen, a simple return key press should break the output but it doesn't. What did i miss?

Comment: the header file: 'conio.h' is not available outside of windows.  suggest not using it, and replace _getch)_ with the universally available getchar() function

Comment: Your `while` only executes at most once.. why not change `while` to `if` and then get rid of the `break`?

Comment: @user3629249: I have included proper header files. So i m pretty sure that no other header files are required.

Comment: in the user prompt, the code should mention that the valid characters are A...   Then the code should validate the character as being in the range (inclusive) of A...Z

Comment: @Dhananjay Could you show what pattern  you are trying to output?

Comment: If the code were commented, the we would not have to reverse engineer the code to try and determine what each 'for' loop was trying to accomplish

Comment: @user3629249: I got what you mean. Validating within the limit does make sense.

Comment: @Dmitri: Yup a little change with if is good thanks.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Lets just say i input D
                                 A
                               ABA
                             ABCBA                                                                                                          
                          ABCDCBA

Comment: regarding this line: 'while (scanf_s("%c", &ch, 1) == 1)' if the code were to actually make more than one pass through this loo (which it does not), the next character to be input would be a newline.  probably not what you want.

Comment: @user3629249: Exactly. Although i didnt had the idea untill i used if an made couple of changes.

Comment: regarding the call to scanf_s().  the %c format specifier will only input one keystroke, so there is no need to guard against buffer overflow so a simple scanf(" %c", &ch) would be sufficient

Comment: @VladfromMoscow : Pardon me printf("%c", row); this statement after the first for statement was just a tracker. I have removed it.

Comment: I ran the program, (after getting a clean compile by removing the include for conio.h and replacing _getch() with getchar() after entering a character in the range A...Z, watching the formatted output,  then clicking my return key, the program exited. (taking the terminal window with it.)  so please clarify the problem.

Comment: @user3629249: The problem was that i should have include the range A...z. That was causing the problem . Thanks for making it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the code I used to accomplish the desired function

```cpp
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        char ch;
        char j = ' ';
        char ch1 = 'A';
        char row;
        char col1;
        char spaces;
        char col2;

        printf("Enter a character in the range (inclusive) A...Z\n");
        if( (scanf(" %c", &ch) == 1) && (ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'Z' ) )
        {
            for (row = 'A'; row <= ch; row++)
            {
                printf("%c", row);
                for (spaces = ch; spaces >= row; spaces--)
                {
                    printf("%c", j);
                }
                for (col1 = ch1; col1 <= row; col1++)
                {
                    printf("%c", col1);
                }

                for (col2 = col1 - 2; col2 >= ch1; --col2)
                {
                    printf("%c", col2);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            break;
        }

        getchar();
        return 0;
    } // end function: main
```

Comment: Why did you leave the `break;` ? This is probably cause a compile error. and  `getchar();` is not used to delay the exit.